# Why doesn't the application UI storage tab show broadcast variables

Tags: apache-spark

When I broadcast a variable in SPARK, I don't see it in the storage tab of the Apllication web UI. It would be handy to see how much memory it uses. Is there a reason why broadcast variables are not shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem and found this still unresolved ticket from 2014: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3957

It says sending broadcast var info to the driver would open a new (quite unnecessary) channel. The workaround pull request (sending the broadcast info on top of some other info) somehow got lost through time...
https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/2851

Comment: Yes, seems like it hasn't been a priority - which is fair enough. However, we don't need the values sent to the driver, just the web UI. I don't know enough about the internals of spark to know if that is the same thing or not.